# Does SharePoint 2010 have some restrictions for large documents in .html format?

Tags: .net, sharepoint

I have some problem with large sized files I uploaded (via code or via SP interface - it doesn't matter) into a document library. After uploading the file (which has a size more than 10 MB), it has zero content. When I'm working with documents like 1MB or less, everything is ok. Even more, when I upload the same file (size > 10 MB) but with another extension like ".txt", the file is full with data and correct size.
What is the most possible reason for such behavior?

Comment: Are you sure there's nothing else that might cause this? SharePoints has a maximum file size limit of 2GB and by default the limit is set to 50MB.

Comment: I'm not sure but the problem is exist just for .html files for another formats it is good and they are uploading correct. Also I know about SharePoint size limit but it is not related with it (I suppose)